# Display an empty json instead of []

Tags: php

I have a json that is look like this

```
{
    "data": [
       data here
    ]
}
```

and here is how i fill it up

```
$json = array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $json['data'][] = $value;   
        }
```

and here is how i display it

```
echo json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

what if the data for is empty? how can I display an empty json because my php only display `[]` when it is empty

like maybe something like this

```
{
    "data": [

    ]
}
```

Comment: Explicitly define your structure, try `$json = array( 'data' => array() );`

Comment: wow! tysm :D.....,

Comment: @Scuzzy if a java read this does it count as 0 rows?

Comment: Yes, its still an empty array. Your code was only creating "data" when the loop was iterating over records. This will also avoid php index notices.

Comment: @Scuzzy tysm sir :D

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Comment: @Scuzzy sure please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest explicitly defining your structure before adding records to your 'data' index. Currently, the 'data' property is only created during result iteration, which is why you're seeing a string of `[]` wen there are no records.

```
$json = array( 'data' => array() );
```

This will also help to avoid any warnings/notices generated by PHP.